# How do I Eliminate the Recurring Dead Animal Smell Coming From Registers?

Tags: hvac

There is an intermittent smell of dead animal coming from the floor registers in our house. Comes and goes. First, we smelled it only near the fireplace. Opened the flue and stuck my nose up the chimney and didn’t smell it but could smell it when I was near the fireplace. Then the smell went away and came back a few weeks later. Now,the exact same smell is coming from two bedrooms that are next to each other. Usually, the smell happens when the heat isn't running. Then the heat runs and smell goes away. This has been happening for three years. We have a gas furnace. Thanks.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Yes, please revise to ask something specific. Update your title to reflect that question. Take the [tour]. Does anyone else agree with your aromatic assessment? Maybe you're misinterpreting it.

Comment: Dead animals dry out in under three years. Maybe it's sewer gas. Or do you think that there's a steady stream of dead animals?

Comment: Is my question not visible? I can see it above the comments. Dead animal smell comes and goes. Coming from floor registers. Smells worse when heat is not running. When heat runs, smell gets better. Goes away for a few days and comes back. Same smell. We have gas furnace.

Comment: Tomcat pee can often sort of smell like a dead animal.  And it is hard to get rid off.

Comment: Step 1: get rid of the dead animal?